# Point-In-Time recovery for a deleted RDS database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

This is a pretty small question, maybe the answer is too obvious that I can't see it.

Can you still do Point-In-Time recovery for an RDS database instance if that instance was deleted? Or is all the data since the last snapshot gone?

To clarify a bit better (an example):

Last snapshot was on 05/xx/xxxx at 23:00 (11PM). My database got deleted by accident on 06/xx/xxxx at 05:00 (5AM). Is the data created in the 6 hours gone, or can I still use Point-In-Time recovery for that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete an RDS instance all its automated snapshots are deleted, and all the backing resources are deleted. The only thing left to restore from will be any manual snapshots you created, or any other manual backups you created via something like mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't choose to save a snapshot of the instance when deleting it (saving a snapshot is the default action, and you must choose to not have one created), all you have left are any manual snapshots.